# C# Webform re-route if request doesn't contain specific string

Tags: c#, webforms, query-string, reroute

I'm creating on a website using Webform, I'm encountering a problem and would like your help/ideas/solutions.

For some pages, I need to check if the query string contains a specific string, if this query string doesn't exist, empty or isn't a number, I will redirect the current request to another page.
I'm able to do this with checking query string in code behind in **every pages**.

What I would want is just to write a **global query string handler** to do this for me so I don't have to rewrite the code every time. This global handler would run every time every time there's a request to server, it checks these conditions:
- the location of the page being requested
- the query string

I couldn't find any documents about this. If anybody knows, please enlighten me! Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered putting this check inside a masterpage?

Comment: Masterpage's page load will be loaded last (after the child's page load) so it's not good